# Unable to display UART character data sent from STM32F407G Discovery Board (TX) to Ubuntu(or Raspian) on Rasperry Pi 3 Model B (RX)

Tags: stm32, embedded, uart, serial

**Solved.** The problem was a bad board & then appending extra "\n" in the output after reading from via "C".

---

I'm trying to send data via UART from STM32F407G Discovery Board micro-controller to RasperryPi 3 Model B running Ubuntu.

I was able to send data using STM32F407G Discovery Board "C" libraries & display that output on TeraTerm & Putty apps on Windows via serial-usb interface wire.

**My goal is to create my own simple serial port reader/writer program that displays the UART character data thaw which will come from  STM32F407G.**

**Below is the relevant snippet of the transmission code on the STM32F407G side:**

```
void print_mpu_values_to_uart(mpu6050_device *dev, UART_HandleTypeDef* huart, long print_delay_millisecs) {

    if (NULL != dev) {
        char str[120];
        char *pStr = str;
        clear_uart_message(pStr, sizeof(str));
        /* Format data */
        sprintf(str,
                "dev=%.2X,Ax=%2.4f,Ay=%2.4f,Az=%2.4f,Gx=%2.4f,Gy=%2.4f,Gz=%2.4f\r\n",
                dev->address, dev->pMpu_6050_data.Ax, dev->pMpu_6050_data.Ay,
                dev->pMpu_6050_data.Az, dev->pMpu_6050_data.Gx,
                dev->pMpu_6050_data.Gy, dev->pMpu_6050_data.Gz);
        //send label
        HAL_UART_Transmit(huart, (uint8_t*) str, sizeof(str), 1000);
        HAL_Delay(print_delay_millisecs);
    }

}
```

**I connected STM32F407G Discovery Board via Serial-USB wire & configured TeraTerm to listen to com port (COM9):**

**See snap of configured serial port values & correct output:**

[image]

So far all is as expected & good.

I have confirmed the STM32F407G board, MPU sensors are integrated, and transmission code on  STM32F407G is correct, as expected output is displayed.

**I would like to create my own custom serial receiver on RasperryPi (other linux embedded boards) to further process my data.**

**Based on these online resources:**

[https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html](https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/%7Estrupp/serial.html)
[http://www.ing.iac.es/~docs/external/serial/serial.pdf](http://www.ing.iac.es/%7Edocs/external/serial/serial.pdf)
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

**These are my steps:**

1. I disconnected the usb-serial that was sending data to TeraTerm on Windows and connect my STM32F407G Discovery Board UART to RasperryPi UART pins, like this:

STM UART RX (PA3) to Rasperry UART TX (GPIO 14 PIN 8)
STM UART TX (PA2) to Rasperry UART RX (GPIO 15 PIN 10)

2. UART Receive code on RasperryPi side (Im made sure my buadrate, parity bit, etc are same as TeraTerm settings):

   ```
      #include <iostream>
        #include <stdio.h> /* Standard input/output definitions */
        #include <string.h> /* String function definitions */
        #include <unistd.h> /* UNIX standard function definitions */
        #include <fcntl.h> /* File control definitions */
        #include <errno.h> /* Error number definitions */
        #include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

        using namespace std;

        int open_port(char * port);
        void read_port(int file_descriptor, int buffer_size);
        struct termios SerialPortOptions;
        int main() {
            char * port = "/dev/ttyS0";
            std::cout << "Serial comm..." << port << std::endl;

            /*this program must executed via SUDO*/
            int fd = open_port(port);
            if (fd!=-1) {
                std::cout << port << ", Opened successfully " << std::endl;
                /*
                 * Set the baud rates to 115200...
                 */
                cfsetispeed( & SerialPortOptions, B115200);
                cfsetospeed( & SerialPortOptions, B115200);

                /*
                 *Turn off hardware based flow control (RTS/CTS).
                 */
                SerialPortOptions.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

                /*
                 * Enable the receiver and set local mode...
                 */
                SerialPortOptions.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

                /*For Serial communications with outside devices like serial modems,mice etc NON Cannonical mode is recommended.*/
                SerialPortOptions.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);

                /*setting character size bits*/
                SerialPortOptions.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */
                SerialPortOptions.c_cflag |= CS8; /* Select 8 data bits */

                /* No parity*/
                SerialPortOptions.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
                SerialPortOptions.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
                SerialPortOptions.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
                SerialPortOptions.c_cflag |= CS8;
                tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, & SerialPortOptions);
                //read from serial port

                    read_port(fd, 128);

                close(fd);


            }
            return 0;
        }

        /*References: http://www.ing.iac.es/~docs/external/serial/serial.pdf
         * Page 8-10*/
        int open_port(char * port) {

            int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
            /*
             * O_RDWR  - read write mode
             * O_NOCTTY -  this program doesn't want to be the "controlling terminal" for that port
             * O_NDELAY -  this program doesn't care what state the DCD signal line is in − whether
                        the other end of the port is up and running.
             */
            fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
            cout << "open_port(),fd:" << fd<< endl;
            if (fd == -1) {
                /*
                 * Could not open the port.
                 */
                perror("open_port: Unable to open ");
                perror(port);
            } else {
                fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
            }
            return fd;
        }


    void read_port(int file_descriptor, int buffer_size) {
        char serial_buffer[buffer_size];
        //cout << "read_port(),file_descriptor:" << file_descriptor << endl;
        int total_read= 0;
        int r=0;
        while (true) {
        r = read(file_descriptor, serial_buffer, sizeof(serial_buffer));
        if (r>0) {
            total_read = total_read + r;
        }
        if (total_read >= buffer_size) {
            serial_buffer[buffer_size] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", serial_buffer);
            fflush(stdout);
            cout << "total_read:" << total_read << endl;
            total_read = 0;

        }
    }
   ```

   }

**Ubuntu on RasperryPi, console output snippet:**

```
Serial comm.../dev/ttyS0
open_port(),fd:3
/dev/ttyS0, Opened successfully 
W��k
total_read:128
��k
total_read:128
Y��k
total_read:128
��k
total_read:128

total_read:128
7��k
total_read:128
��k
total_read:128
```

As you can see I cant display the characters correctly but data is being sent to /dev/ttyS0.

**Troubleshooting:**

1. For sanity check, to see if that was actually coming from STM32F407G, I physically disconnect TX (line from STM32F407G) to RX in RasperryPi, data stops flowing & stops printing on console.
2. For further sanity check, I also tried "minicom" on Ubuntu's shell:

sudo minicom -D "/dev/ttyS0" -b 115200

**Minicom output:**

```
CTRL-A Z for help | 115200 8N1 | NOR | Minicom 2.7.1 | VT102 | Offline | ttyS0
5…Y{‚A‚A‚A‚A‚ˆžaÊBœ"WWñö‹]ÁIÈœ"7WšÔä†Q2”UgÛV5F[uIœ"wSË€@‚A‚‚Aþˆžaœ"YM÷‹\ÁÅYÈ5…Qêœ"7[ì†S*ŠZZŸQ:”[
```

As you can see Minicom also gets data its not formatted correctly & garbage.

3. I though this might have to do with endianess, the STM32 has ARM Cortex M4 which according to the document (PM0214 Programming manual STM32 Cortex®-M4 MCUs and MPUs programming manual) **is by default little-endian**, **also running the command "lscpu" on the RasperryPi 3 model B, shows the Cortex-A53 which is also Little Endian based (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#64/32-bit_architecture), so I highly doubt the issue is endianess.**

**Based on user comments I tried different baud rates here are the results:**

```
BAUDRATE:   OUTPUT TERMINAL & ENVIRONMENT:      RESULT:
115,200     TeraTerm/Putty (Windows)        Good (can see correct data)
115,200     C Program (Linux Ubuntu of Pi)      Garbage & Bad format

57,600          TeraTerm/Putty (Windows)        Good (can see correct data)
57,600          C Program (Linux Ubuntu of Pi)      Garbage & Bad format

38,400          TeraTerm/Putty (Windows)        Good (can see correct data)
38,400          C Program (Linux Ubuntu of Pi)      Garbage & Bad format

19200       TeraTerm/Putty (Windows)        Good (can see correct data)
19200       C Program (Linux Ubuntu of Pi)      Garbage & Bad format & also stops after few lines

14400       TeraTerm/Putty (Windows)        Good (can see correct data) 
14400       C Program (Linux Ubuntu of Pi)      Not supported & constant not present in termios.h 

9600        TeraTerm/Putty (Windows)        Good (can see correct data) 
9600        C Program (Linux Ubuntu of Pi)      Garbage & Bad format

4800        TeraTerm/Putty (Windows)        Good (can see correct data) 
4800        C Program (Linux Ubuntu of Pi)      Garbage & Bad format
```

**Another attempt:**, i changed the OS to Raspian &  followed this blog (https://www.circuits.dk/setup-raspberry-pi-3-gpio-uart/). I wrote this small **Python script:**

```
import serial

serialport = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=4800, timeout=3.0)

while True:
    rcv = port.read(120)
    print(rcv)
```

Still getting garbage output!

**How can I alter my C code on the RasperryPi to display the incoming UART characters properly?**

**PARTIAL-SOLUTION:** Based on user input I tried UART from my original Pi board to actual PC & also UART loop, I was not able to get output. At this point I suspect the board, therefore I switched my board with another Pi 3 Model version B. After instaling minicom & disabking shell over UART. I can see meaningful minicom output:

[image]

**I wrote a simpler version of C program above:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    struct termios serial;
    char buffer[120];

    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Usage: %s [device]\n\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Opening %s\n", argv[1]);

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if (fd == -1) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &serial) < 0) {
        perror("Getting configuration");
        return -1;
    }

    // Set up Serial Configuration
    serial.c_iflag = 0;
    serial.c_oflag = 0;
    serial.c_lflag = 0;
    serial.c_cflag = 0;

    serial.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    serial.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    serial.c_cflag = B115200 | CS8 | CREAD;

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &serial); // Apply configuration
    int flag =0;
    int read_count = 0; 
    while (flag!=-1)
    {
            int rcount = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if (rcount < 0) {
                perror("Read");
                flag= -1;
            break;
            }
        else if (rcount>0)
        {
            //printf("Received %d characters\n", rcount);
                buffer[rcount] = '\0';
                printf("%s", buffer);
        }
            else {
                //read nothing, do nothing.
            }   


    }

    close(fd);
}
```

Im getting expected output:

dev=D2,Ax=-0.9922,Ay=0.0566,Az=0.8118,Gx=-0.2672,Gy=-1.0611,Gz=0.7634
dev=D0,Ax=-0.0664,Ay=0.0955,Az=0.8772,Gx=-0.6947,Gy=-0.9924,Gz=-1.4351
dev=D2,Ax=-0.9958,Ay=0.0535,Az=0.8113,Gx=-0.2824,Gy=-1.0687,Gz=0.7328
dev=D0,Ax=-0.0664,Ay=0.0962,Az=0.8818,Gx=-0.4656,Gy=-0.8397,Gz=-1.5420
dev=D2,Ax=-0.9961,Ay=0.0554,Az=0.8169,Gx=0.0305,Gy=-0.9771,Gz=0.6870
dev=D0,Ax=-0.0566,Ay=0.0999,Az=0.8813,Gx=-0.4809,Gy=-0.9466,Gz=-1.7023
dev=D2,Ax=-0.9858,Ay=0.0571,Az=0.8225,Gx=-0.3359,Gy=-0.9084,Gz=0.7023
dev=D0,Ax=-0.0657,Ay=0.0896,Az=0.8850,Gx=-0.7939,Gy=-1.0916,Gz=-1.5191
dev=D2,Ax=-0.9956,Ay=0.0623,Az=0.8191,Gx=-0.1756,Gy=-0.9542,Gz=0.8626
dev=D0,Ax=-0.0632,Ay=0.1025,Az=0.8782,Gx=-0.9008,Gy=-1.0076,Gz=-1.3893
dev=D2,Ax=-0.9985,Ay=0.0576,Az=0.8252,Gx=-0.1221,Gy=-0.7252,Gz=0.8702

**Solved.** The problem was a bad board & then appending extra "\n" in the output after reading from via "C".

Really apprecaite the community support.

Comment: might be an encoding issue

Comment: @EdwinFairchild, please be kind enough to expand? How does TeraTerm or Putty automatically convert & display? Im sending over characters and not raw bytes.

Comment: Maybe the clocks of the two devices are too imprecise relative to each other. Try a slower baud rate and if that works then you may need more precise clock sources.

Comment: create a nice simple serial program on the stm32 side. Send out a few bytes in a known order. Like "ABC". Then loop forever. Then on the PI side, capture the data to a file as binary data. Hit reset on the stm32 a couple of times to make sure you have several iterations of "ABC".  Hex dump the short binary file on the pi side and see what is in it.

Comment: Not sure this line is correct: "HAL_UART_Transmit(huart, (uint8_t*) str, sizeof(str), 1000);" sizeof(str) will always be the length of the array. I think you would be better of using strlen(str) instead of sizeof(str). Also you would be better off using snprintf() instead of sprintf(). Just to make sure you don't overrun your buffer.

Comment: If it works with teraterm on PC, it should work with any terminal on Rpi too. Have you configured the Rpi linux kernel to properly route the UART RX and TX pins to the IO pins?

Comment: @kkrambo, please see updated results, I recompiled for baud rates between 115,200 down to 4,800 same results. TeraTerm/Putty is good on Windows, but the custom C program using "termios" library is no good on Pi running Ubuntu OS. See details above.

Comment: Have you connected GND on the RPi to GND on the STM board?

Comment: @MarcosG. Yes GND of Pi is connected to GND on STM.

Comment: I see... Out of curiosity, I just tested my RPi 4 running Ubuntu 20.10 and I could not manage to send or receive anything on its `/dev/ttyAMA0` port with minicom. After opening the task just hangs in there not responding and I have to kill it... I only installed Ubuntu a couple of weeks back so I never had the opportunity to test the board's serial port. Have you tried something else than Ubuntu? I never had any trouble whatsoever on my RPis with Raspbian... I will get back if I have the time to run more tests on Ubuntu

Comment: @MarcosG. I will try this either tonight or tomorrow & let you know. Appreciated.

Comment: @MarcosG. Yes STM GND is connected to Pi GND.

Comment: @MarcosG. 1st i really appreciate your follow up. I just tried the same setup if Raspian Lite on the same Pi board using minicom 2.7.1. Again garbage. I used 115200 baud rate. I will try other baud rates by tonight.

Comment: @MarcosG. I followed this blog line by line, even the custom Python outputs garbage.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried the script for the loopback test at the end of the blog? you should connect a wire from RX to TX on the RPi and test that script or minicom. If you still get garbage on the loopback test I don't know what to tell you other than changing the power supply on the Pi for another one less noisy and/or more powerful. If that does not work either then I think you might need a new board. But I would be very surprised to see a serial port go bad like that, I've tested and tortured many boards; sometimes some things really break down completely... Do you have a spare board to try?

Comment: I forgot something. Can you show the part of the code where you set up the UART for the ST board? There might be something wrong in there. I imagine you have tried to connect your Prolific USB cable to the RPi already, right?

Comment: Instead of connecting hardware serial pins together, try using the same USB-Serial converter on a USB port of RPi and see if it works.

Comment: @MarcosG. I switch the Pi to another Pi 3 Model B. Installed everything , including minicom & I can see expected output on minimcom.

Comment: @MarcosG.See the updated post, Im able to read via minicom & C. However Pi reads much faster than STM can write. Maybe i can try higher baud rate on the Pi side.

Comment: The loopback test was quite definitive. Too bad that the UART broke down. Maybe it was already like that from factory or it catched a spike of static or something.

Comment: @MarcosG. Im not sure why you didnt get the bounty, I actually up voted your comment. Voltage Spike just rehashed what we said & posted an answer, no wander he has 57,000 points. Very fair.

Comment: No worries. Since I did not write an answer I cannot get any votes or bounty. Honestly, it was quite a strange issue with the UART being bad, in my opinion, that makes it an unsolvable issue. I don't particularly like boilerplate answers that look like they are coming from the IT support desk.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (I did this on the RP4 just 2 days ago at the same baudrate and an STM32F405 and it worked fine after a 'gotcha') these are some things to check:

1. Make sure you have a ground between boards (TX and RX is not enough)
2. Check the TX voltage level of the output (with an oscilloscope or logic analyzer) and make sure it's 3.3V for the Pi (which it should be coming from the STM32F407G, but you never know sometimes ports get blown out.
3. Check the clock rate on the STM32F, I don't have my code with me but I do know there was a problem with one of the clocks that generated the baud rate wrong (there was a multiplier somewhere in the HAL code that was supposed to be 8Mhz higher and was generating an incorrect baud rate (the baud rate was 8x lower, if I remember right). (this is also why it's good to check the baud rate with a scope or logic analyzer). I'll find the error when I get a chance and update.

Also Minicom is not a good way to check sometimes because it will auto adjust the baud rate, whatever COM program you use, make sure you force the baud rate to a fixed known value.

Comment: appreciate the input all the things you mentioned I had already tried in the original post. I have already posted the solution. The problem as 1) faulty Pi UART 2) small bug in the C's console print logic.

Comment: 1) The definitive answer was MarcosG's loopback test that identified a faulty UART on my Pi. When Swiped my Pi with another Pi everything worked. Another smaller issue was extra "\n" in C's console output. However, I still appreciate the wisdom. Any thoughts on how STM to Pi communication over UART may go wrong in the production system (mission-critical) application? Strictly focusing on the UART aspect.

Comment: *minicom...will auto adjust the baud rate...*; are you sure you are not confusing it with something else? The one I have does not have any auto baud rate detection.